# jquery find('object') problem in ie6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem with ie6 when searching for an inserted object with jquery. I do something like this:

```
var obj = $('<div></div>').html($('#embedded_video').val()).remove().find('object');
```

where in the embedded_video textbox i insert an object taken from youtube or so. This works great in FF and IE7&8 but does not seem to work in ie6. I tried to modify the command to look for something else like ...`find('a')` and it also works in ie6 so the problem only appears when i search for 'object'.

Can anyone help find another method to do the search?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious to find out more. What do you get when you do this. Do you see you object in the html?

```
alert($('<div></div>').html($('#embedded_video').val()).remove().html());
```

Also, what happens if you use closest() instead of find(). Although, if you're looking for more than one object, this maybe isn't for you.

Comment: "<object><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZrGMXi3zrnM&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZrGMXi3zrnM&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed></object>"
becomes:
"<EMBED src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZrGMXi3zrnM&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></EMBED>"

Comment: so i guess the problem isn't with find but with objects in text areas in ie6